# How to install GraphicsMagick plug-in under win11?

Tags: graphicsmagick

I plan to enable jxl and avif two image formats in my project. I see that GraphicsMagick already supports this, but additional installation is required:

- GraphicsMagick requires the heif library from

  https://github.com/strukturag/libheif

  and the libde265 library from

  https://github.com/strukturag/libde265
- GraphicsMagick requires the JPEG XL (JXL) library (release 0.7.0 or
  later) from https://github.com/libjxl/libjxl to read and write JPEG
  XL files.

But I don't know how to do it? I can't find a reference.

I have no experience in c language, but I have installed vs 2022 and can perform some simple compilation operations.
Thanks！

Comment: I don't have, or want, Windows, but AFAIK many folk use something called `chocolatey` to install packages/programs.